# Change a Database Column from UNSIGNED to BINARY without converting to string

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table containing IPv4 addresses in an `UNSIGNED INTEGER` column. I'm now changing this to support IPv6 addresses, as returned by `INET6_ATON()` which requires a `VARBINARY(16)` column type.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/inet6_aton/

How can I alter the existing column to preserve its contents?

```
ALTER TABLE hitcounts CHANGE ip ip BINARY(16);
```

The above command seems to be converting the unsigned integer values into the string equivalent which is not what I want.

### Demonstration

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE hitcounts (ip INTEGER UNSIGNED);
INSERT INTO hitcounts VALUES (INET_ATON('78.156.181.3')),(INET_ATON('64.255.180.66')),(INET_ATON('31.126.241.81'));
SELECT * FROM hitcounts;
+------------+
| ip         |
+------------+
| 1318892803 |
| 1090499650 |
|  528413009 |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

ALTER TABLE hitcounts MODIFY COLUMN ip VARBINARY(16);
SELECT * FROM hitcounts;
+------------+
| ip         |
+------------+
| 1318892803 |
| 1090499650 |
| 528413009  |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

While the converted ip values appear to have been preserved, they have in fact been converted into an ASCII string (note the left-alignment of the third row compared to the right-alignment used when it was a true number). Attempting to get the IP address will fail:

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA(ip) FROM hitcounts;
+----------------+
| INET6_NTOA(ip) |
+----------------+
| NULL           |
| NULL           |
| NULL           |
+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: What was the datatype before the attempted `ALTER`?

Comment: it was an UNSIGNED INTEGER column

Comment: Hmmm... May take an extra step:  Note that `INET6_NTOA(INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA(1318892803)))` --> `78.156.181.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to alter the column as described, and then update the column to convert to binary string as produced by INET6_ATON():

```
UPDATE hitcounts SET ip = INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA(ip));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the INET6 functions deal with 4-byte binary for IPv4 and 16-byte binary for IPv6, I think this is closer to 'correct':

```
ALTER TABLE hitcounts MODIFY COLUMN ip VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL;
```

The `VAR` is because `INET6_ATON('1.2.3.4')` generates a `BINARY(4)` string.

I have not verified that merely converting `UNSIGNED` to `VARBINARY(16)` will preserve the IPv4 values correctly.

MySQL 5.6.3 or MariaDB 10.0.12 is needed.  (At some earlier point, I think MariaDB was using a different spelling: `INET6_NTOP()` and `INET6_PTON()`).

Comment: Thanks for your input. `VARBINARY` also exhibits the problem I was having. I've added some code to my question to clarify the issue. I'm not sure now if the string conversion is a red herring, it seems that `INET6_ATON` produces different output than `INET_ATON` for IPv4 addresses, so perhaps there just isn't a way to convert the values without using `INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA())`, which like you point out, isn't available on older MySQL/MariaDB servers.